# SQl code analysis

Tags: mysql, sql

Please i need help to analyze this code . I am bit confuse to interpret what it means . This is not a code i write but some else . 
All i need to do is to understand it and able to implement it
 somewhere else . Thank you

```
$sql  = "select t0.userid,concat(t3.firstname,',',t3.lastname) as name,count(*) as quizs,sum(if(t0.finalgrade > 0,1,0)) as quiz, sum(t0.finalgrade) as grade";
$sql .= " from mdl_grade_grades t0";
$sql .= " left join mdl_grade_items t1 on( t0.itemid= t1.id and t1.courseid = 37 and (t1.itemname like '%Daily Quiz%' or t1.itemname in ('Mid Term Exam','FINAL EXAM')))";
$sql .= " left join mdl_user t3 on(t3.id=t0.userid)"; 
$sql .= " where t0.userid >= 480";
$sql .= " group by t3.firstname,t3.lastname";
$res  = mysql_query($sql);
$response->totalcount = mysql_num_rows($res);

$sql .= " Order by  t3.firstname,t3.lastname";
$sql .= " Limit " .$start ."," .$limit ;
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
    $attend = $row->gquiz / $row->quizs;
    $grade  = $row->grade / $row->gquiz;
    $response->items[] = array('id' => $row->userid,'name' => $row->name,'attend' => $attend,'grade' => $grade);    
}
//      
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: This is not sql server code. It is mysql.

Comment: What part(s) of this don't you understand?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use code formats wisely; quoting yourself in bold makes you look like those kings that speak of themselves in third person. Thank you!

Comment: Yes i know its mysql . My mistake when posting the question . However, the part I don't understand  is the arithmetic operation

Comment: Do you mean the `sum()` function? It, well, sums rows. `1` + `4` + `6` makes `11` .

Comment: yes the sum function sum(if(t0.finalgrade > 0,1,0)) as quiz, sum(t0.finalgrade) as grade

Comment: @HarrisMorris . You should break it down into bits, and anaylse it. Aka, the brackets.  It is `summing ( If final grade > 0, use 1 else 0 ) as quiz`. So basically, giving the total number of people who got more than 0 as their final grade.

Answer (score 0):

The function `sum(if(t0.finalgrade > 0,1,0))` actually counts the number of records having a `finalgrade` greater than 0.
The function `sum(t0.finalgrade)` simply sums the `finalgrade` of all records.

Answer (score 0):

`IF()` is a builtin function and it's [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

> ```
> IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)
> ```
>
> If expr1 is TRUE (expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL), IF() returns expr2.
>   Otherwise, it returns expr3.

In your case:

```
if(t0.finalgrade > 0,1,0)
```

If final grade is greater than 0 then return 1, else return 0.

Finally, `SUM()` sums all these zeros and ones.

PHP code does not play any role in this MySQL logic.